# how to store many objects in a byte array

Tags: java, arrays, serialization

I am coding in java and I have a problem
I am using an interface (that the teacher gave us and we cant change it), the interface obligate you to implement a function with a byte array is input and through this array you can transfer any data you want.

I need to pass a few different objects with unknown size ,is there a way to do it? I can obviously put the size of every object at the beginning but this is very difficult is there any easier way to do it?

I also need to pass data in a byte array from another language like c or cpp
so the technique must be non specific to java

here is a simple example of what the code looks like

```
void myFunc(byte[] arr)
{
    byte[] name; // arr[0:10] string in ascii
    byte[] lastName; //arr[10:k] string in ascii
    byte[] currentUnixTime; //arr[k:arr.lenfth] this is an int

    some operations.....
}
```

Comment: What kind of objects? Note that not everything in Java can be serialized to bytes in a meaningful way.

Comment: Can you please post some code to show us what you tried and what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

So without further details you can generically send `Object` through serialization but it might not always be a good idea.  Here is a fairly generic implementation of `Object` serialization.

```
interface Sender {
    void write(OutputStream outputStream, Object... objects);

    List<Object> read(InputStream inputStream);
}

class Homework implements Sender {
    @Override
    public void write(OutputStream stream, Object... objects) {
        for (Object obj : objects) {
            try (ObjectOutputStream objStream = new ObjectOutputStream(stream)) {
                objStream.writeObject(obj);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public List<Object> read(InputStream stream) {
        List<Object> objectList = new ArrayList<>();
        try (ObjectInputStream objStream = new ObjectInputStream(stream)) {

            Object obj;
            while ((obj = objStream.readObject()) != null) {
                objectList.add(obj);
            }
        } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return objectList;
    }
}
```

Edit: I misunderstood the question.  Here is a implementation that uses `byte[]`s

```
interface Sender {
    byte[] write(Object... objects);

    List<Object> read(byte[] bytes);
}

class Homework implements Sender {
    @Override
    public byte[] write(Object... objects) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        try (ObjectOutputStream objStream = new ObjectOutputStream(out)) {
            for (Object obj : objects) {
                objStream.writeObject(obj);
            }
            objStream.flush();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return out.toByteArray();
    }

    @Override
    public List<Object> read(byte[] bytes) {
        List<Object> objectList = new ArrayList<>();
        ByteArrayInputStream byteInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
        try (ObjectInputStream objStream = new ObjectInputStream(byteInputStream)) {

            Object obj;
            while ((obj = objStream.readObject()) != null) {
                objectList.add(obj);
            }
        } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return objectList;
    }
}
```

Then to use it.

```
Homework homework = new Homework();
String helloWorld = "hello world";
byte[] helloBytes = homework.write(helloWorld);
assert homework.read(helloBytes).get(0).equals(helloWorld);
```

Comment: Where is the byte array from the question?

Comment: I dont understand how do I send and receive data here

Comment: See updated response, I misunderstood at first the ask.

Comment: if the datasource returned from the `native` method returns bytes then yes you can pass the bytes to this and read objects.  However this doesn't include the c portion that is quite different. See this: https://medium.com/@bschlining/a-simple-java-native-interface-jni-example-in-java-and-scala-68fdafe76f5f

Comment: but how can I write data like this in cpp before sending to java?

Answer (score 0):

In the end what I did was this - 
I converted to base 32 every object that I wanted to send ,then in between each converted object I added a ',' to separate the object (since ',' isn't needed for base 32 representation).
after that the analysis was simple